# foundation 5 orbit slider on load misaligned

Tags: javascript, slider, size, zurb-foundation, orbit

I’m pretty new to foundation and I’m LOVING it.

But I’ve hit a road block trying to combine the orbit slider and interchange features.

This link is to the page I’m working on: 
http://dintinoconte.com/home/

On load, the slider loads fully but then sinks behind the rest of the content.

Here’s the kicker.. as soon as the window is resized, even by a single pixel, everything fit and works perfectly!
** All the foundation files are in their original state, I have not performed any modifications

Comment: Please include the code samples you are discussing

Comment: this is the orbit slider @BillyBigPotatoes,
http://chopapp.com/#c73h82fv, you may also view the source of the page in your browser